# Probability Question on a dice roll - Conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

I have a question which I have a hard time wrapping my head around it.

> If I roll a dice three times, and I know that I got three different numbers, 
>   what is the probability that one of the numbers is $2$?

I thought to first calculate the probability to get different numbers which is:

$$\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{6^3} = \frac{5}{9}$$

Then I know you need to use here Bayes' law since we know we got different numbers. So it is:

$P$(getting $2$| getting different numbers) = $P$(getting different numbers $\cap$ getting $2$ | getting different numbers)

Here I got stuck. I think it is the probability of getting $2$ ($1/6$) and then divide it by $5/9$.

Comment: You could also note that since you will obtain exactly $3$ of $6$ possible values, and all $6$ are equally likely to be obtained, each value (including $2$) has $3/6$ chances of being one of the three obtained.  So the answer you want must be $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take into account the order of the rolls,

- there are $6 \times 5 \times 4 =120$ equally likely ways of rolling three dice and getting different values
- Of these, there are different ways of getting a $2$:

  - $1 \times 5 \times 4=20$ if the $2$ comes first
  - $5 \times 1 \times 4=20$ if the $2$ comes second
  - $5 \times 4 \times 1=20$ if the $2$ comes third

So the overall conditional probability is $\frac{20+20+20}{120}=\frac12$ of getting a $2$ if three different values are rolled.

A faster way is to say that there are three different values shown and three not shown.  By symmetry, $2$ is equally likely to be in either set so has a conditional probability of $\frac36=\frac12$ of being rolled.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about the probability that you *don't* see a 2. On the first roll of the dice, you have 6 options: $1,2,3,4,5,$ and $6$, which means your probability of *not* rolling a $2$ is $5/6$. Suppose you roll a $6$. Then, since you require all rolls to be distinct, you have 5 options for the next roll: $1,2,3,4,$ and $5$, meaning your probability of *not* rolling a $2$ is $4/5$. Say you roll a $3$. Then you have 4 options for your next roll: $1,2,4,$ and $5$, which means your probability of *not* rolling a $2$ is $3/4$. So, out of three distinct rolls, the probability of never rolling a $2$ is $$\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{4}{5} \times \frac{3}{4} =\frac{1}{2}. $$ 
Then, since the probability of *never* rolling a $2$ is $1/2$, the probability of seeing at least one $2$ is $1-\frac{1}{2}$=$\frac{1}{2}$.